# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class com.example.schema.AssetSchemaV1$PersistentAsset

Tags: hibernate, corda

`PersistentAsset` sample definition:

```
/**
 * The family of schemas for [Asset].
 */
object AssetSchema

/**
 * An [Asset] schema.
 */
object AssetSchemaV1 : MappedSchema(
        schemaFamily = AssetSchema.javaClass,
        version = 1,
        mappedTypes = listOf(PersistentAsset::class.java)) {
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "asset_states", indexes = arrayOf(Index(name = "asset_linear_id_idx", columnList = "linear_id"),
            Index(name = "asset_owner_idx", columnList = "asset_owner")))
    class PersistentAsset(
            @Column(name = "cusip")
            var cusip: String,

            @Column(name = "asset_owner")
            var owner: String,

            @Column(name = "trade_id")
            var tradeId: String,

            @Column(name = "collateral_status")
            var status: String

    ) : PersistentState() {
        constructor() : this("", "", "", "")
    }
}
```

But when I run below query inside the FlowLogic:

```
val session = DatabaseTransactionManager.current().session
val criteriaBuilder = session.criteriaBuilder
val criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Array<Any>::class.java)
val fromAsset = criteriaQuery.from(PersistentAsset::class.java)
criteriaQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.array(fromAsset.get<String>(PersistentAsset::cusip.name)))
val cusips = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery).resultList
```

it throws: **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class com.example.schema.AssetSchemaV1$PersistentAsset**

Don't know why I'm receiving this error after having `PersistentAsset` schema class annotated with `@Entity`

Comment: did you add @Id for primary key??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flows do not expose a Hibernate session so there isn't built-in support for JPQL. You can use `ServiceHub.jdbcSession` to query the node's database within a flow instead.

Here's an example:

```
val results = serviceHub.jdbcSession().prepareStatement(
    "select * from ASSET_STATES"
).executeQuery()

while (results.next()) {
    val cussip = results.getString("cussip")
    val assetOwner = results.getString("asset_owner")
    val tradeId = results.getString("trade_id")
    val collateralStatus = results.getString("collateral_status")
}
```

Please note that as of Corda V2, flows are not checkpointed during potentially long-running database operations.

Comment: Thanks, Joel. I'm already aware of jdbcSession. I was actually trying to do with JPAQL because tend to void writing native sql queries.